# Connection to IBM WebSphere MQ via Powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0, ibm-mq

I am new to powershell. I need to connect to IBM WebSphere MQ Explorer via powershell script. I have already installed IBM library to support MQ Explorer connection. But I am not getting any connection commands to connect to the QueManagers in MQ Explorer. Please guide me.

Comment: Do you need to connect to a queue manager using powershell commands? There is mo74 support pack which adds WebSphere MQ administration capabilities to Windows PowerShell. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24017698

Comment: I have already added this library to existing powershell. Can you please give me the commands to connect to Queue managers

Comment: What type of operations you want to do it? It is for administration of queue managers using powershell. There is a file by name "powershellcookbook.pdf" inside the zip file. You can look at that for the commands.

Comment: I need to drop messages in Queues of MQ manager. Please let ,e know the commands for it

Comment: when I am using this command no QUEUE Manager is displayed: Get-WMQQueueManager | Select Name, QueueManagerIdentifier, QueueManagerDescription | Sort-Object Name -descending

Comment: Are you using the latest version of mo74?By setting the env variable "$DebugPreference = "Continue"  in the powershell window and if you run the same command,few debug statements will be displayed. See if they are of any use. For sending messages Page 18 of the powershellcookbook.pdf has the sequence of commands that you have to execute

Comment: it is showing found 0 local queue managers. I have MQ Explorer installed in my system and Queue manager is in connected state then why this statement is getting displayed. Please explain

Comment: What version of MQ are you using? Can you paste the output of the command here. You can send a mail to the people listed in the first page of mo74.pdf

Comment: DEBUG: Getting the registry information
DEBUG: Finding qmgrs in the mqs file if it exists?
DEBUG: 1 queue manager names to look for
DEBUG: Looking for qmgr: *
DEBUG: Found 0 matching local queue managers

Comment: the MQ version that I am using is "Version: 7.5.0.2"

Comment: Can you just execute "Get-WMQQueueManager" and paste here what you got as an output. mo74 looks for the mqs.ini file if there is any queue manager.Then only it will try to establish a connection

Comment: DEBUG: Getting the registry information
DEBUG: Finding qmgrs in the mqs file if it exi
DEBUG: 1 queue manager names to look for
DEBUG: Looking for qmgr: *
DEBUG: Found 0 matching local queue managers

Comment: @subbaraoc can you please suggest anything after seeing the debug logs

Comment: Sure.Please give me some time,will have to install 7502 and try it out.Tried on MQ v8.0 and it worked fine for me. Will let you know by tomorrow

Comment: I did try with the latest fixpack of 7.5 and it works fine for me.Can you tell me your whole scenario so that i can try the same. Is the queue manager created using MQ v7.5 or older version of MQ?

Comment: The queue manager is created using MQ v7.5